# Maven could not resolve dependencies/ find artifcat when its already present in .m2 repo

Tags: java, maven, jboss, maven-2, jboss6.x

I am trying to build jboss 6.2.2 from source. I have configure the settings.xml to use the official jboss repository as described [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.2/html/Development_Guide/Configure_the_JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform_Maven_Repository_Using_the_Maven_Settings.html).

However midway i am getting error

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project jboss-as-clustering-jgroups: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.jboss.as:jboss-as-clustering-jgroups:jar:7.3.2.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.jboss.as:jboss-as-clustering-common:jar:tests:7.3.2.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]

But when i see the .m2 repository it seems like it is being downloaded correctly and the jar is present there. I tried deleting the whole jboss-as-clustering-common folder and doing a fresh mvn install, but i got the same error, even though this folder was downloaded again. I also tried mvn clean and did a build again, but to no use. What can be possibly wrong?

I think jboss-as-clustering-common is a dependency of jboss-as-clustering-jgroups. Both poms are attached.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show the part of your `pom.xml` file where you reference these dependencies?

Comment: Attached above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use it this way

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
<artifactId>jboss-as-clustering</artifactId>
<version>${Pick a version which you need to use}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
<artifactId>jboss-as-clustering-common</artifactId>
<version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
<artifactId>jboss-as-clustering-jgroups</artifactId>
<version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```